# Swapping the order of name initials and surnames of authors in bibliography when using apacite

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apacite

I am using the `[natbiba]apacite` package. I have written out the commands using `\renewcommand` and fixed most of the cite to match journal requirements. However, I am stuck with the following final changes.

1) After the first author, all subsequent authors have initials of name with no commas and then surname. 
 
2) Comma instead of period before url 
 
3) Color and underline the hyperlinked URL

*Current Citation:*
 
Abernethy, M. A., Kuang, Y. F., & Qin, B. 2015. The influence of ceo power on compensation contract design. *The Accounting Review* 90 (4): 1265-1306. https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971

*Desired Citation:*
 
Abernethy, M. A., Y. F. Kuang, and B. Qin. 2015. The influence of ceo power on compensation contract design. *The Accounting Review* 90 (4): 1265-1306, https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971

```
\begin{filecontents}{tempfile.bib}
    @article{abernethy2015influence,
        title={The influence of CEO power on compensation contract design},
        author={Abernethy, Margaret A and Kuang, Yu Flora and Qin, Bo},
        journal={The Accounting Review},
        volume={90},
        number={4},
        pages={1265--1306},
        year={2015},
        publisher={American Accounting Association},
        url = {https://doi.org/10.2308/accr-50971}, 
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{doi}
\renewcommand{\doitext}{}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\BBOP}{}%%% Removing parentheses around year in bibliography
    \renewcommand{\BBCP}{}
    \renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{}  % <=== (no "Retrieved from")
 \renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}%change & to and
    %% make a space between volume and issue:
    \renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
        \Bem{#1}%             journal
        \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
        \else
        \unskip{ } {#2}%  volume
        \fi
        \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
        \else
        \unskip~({#3})%      issue number; added the '~'
        \fi
        \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
        \else
        \unskip: {#4}%      pages
        \fi
    }
}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}

\cite{abernethy2015influence}

\bibliography{tempfile}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this by creating my own .bst file and then playing around with the styling in my .bst file. For those looking to create custom bibliography styles and don't know where to start - just start my creating your own .bst file from scratch. It takes time but is much easier to custom style later!